# awscli-local error: cannot import name 'SSOTokenFetcher' from 'botocore.utils'

Tags: aws-cli, localstack

I am getting an error when trying to use awscli-local (https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local):

> user@user:~$ awslocal
>
> cannot import name 'SSOTokenFetcher' from 'botocore.utils'
> (/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/utils.py)

Standard aws-cli works fine.

Versions:

> user@user:~$ aws --version aws-cli/2.9.19
> Python/3.11.4 Linux/6.2.0-34-generic source/x86_64.ubuntu.23
> prompt/off

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with the 'cannot import name SSOTokenFetcher' error from 'botocore.utils'. The problem seems to be a conflict between the installed versions of awsebcli and awscli.

Here's what worked for me:

Uninstall awsebcli and awscli:

```
pip uninstall awsebcli
pip uninstall awscli
```

Reinstall python-openstackclient, ignoring the previously installed packages:

```
pip install -U --ignore-installed python-openstackclient --user
```

Please note that the --user flag installs the package for the current user only, which can help avoid permission issues. Also, remember to use the correct version of pip that corresponds to your Python environment.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was `awslocal` not being compatible with python 3.9 modules.

Needed to use 3.11, like this and it started to work:

```
yum install -y python3.11
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.11 get-pip.py --user
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
pip install --user awscli-local
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Ubuntu I had installed the `awscli` with apt. I removed it and installed with pip instead and it worked:

```
sudo apt remove awscli
pip install awscli
```